# log4j configuration in jar which is used by another application already using log4j

Tags: jar, log4j, propertyconfigurator

My problem is that i'm trying to set up log4j to log into a file from my jar. This jar is used by an application which already uses log4j. My jar is made as maven package shipped with log4j. I'm trying to initialize log4j from property file as such:

"log4j.properties"

```
log4j.appender.FileAppender=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.FileAppender.File=${user.home}/.myproject/myproject.log
log4j.appender.FileAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FileAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yy-MM-dd HH:MM:ss,SSS} [%t] %-5p     %c %x - %m%n
log4j.appender.FileAppender.MaxFileSize=5MB

#myproject is full package name

log4j.logger.myproject=,FileAppender
```

I've included this property file into resources of my jar. I'm loading it with code:

```
try {

            InputStream inputStream = this.getClass().getClassLoader()
                    .getResourceAsStream("log4j.properties");
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.load(inputStream);
            inputStream.close();
            PropertyConfigurator.configure(properties);

        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            BasicConfigurator.configure();
            throw new MyprojectException("log4j.properties not found", e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new MyprojectException("log4j.properties could not be loaded", e);
        }
```

This code is working flawlessly when my jar is not used by an application which uses log4j. But it is, i get an empty log file or for some cases in some applications, no log file is created at all.

I've tried to add an appender manually, not with propertyconfigurator like this:

```
static org.apache.log4j.Logger logger = org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(Myproject.class); 
SimpleLayout layout = new SimpleLayout();    
FileAppender appender = new FileAppender(layout,"C:/out.log",true); 

logger.addAppender(appender);
logger.setLevel(Level.DEBUG);
```

This seems to be working fine, but i'd really want to configure log4j from properties file instead.

I've read lots of threads about how log4j handles multiple instances. I've found out that i cannot alter log4j configuration loaded by properties once it's done by one application. Some have suggested i shall ship my own log4j jar and config and configure with propertyconfigurator, that's what i've tried and as you can see it didn't work. I'm curious why my second example is working and the first is not. How can i solve this problem?

notes:
I do not want to alter the log4jconfigs of the applications that use my jar file.
I've also found out that there is -Dlog4j.configuration system property that could be used, but my jar is not an executeable jar file, it gets loaded by Class.forName

Any help is appreciated,

Thanks in advance